# Have there been any other festival-type events like Winter Bash in the past?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-history

I've been active for a few years and I don't remember seeing anything like this in the past.  Is this a first for Stack or did I just miss them in the past?

Comment: Some years ago there was a ninja themed celebration, but that went largely unnoticed.

Comment: Then there was the robot gala (scrapped partway through due to technical complications), the zombie event (somewhat monotonous, but hard to give up once you were into it), and the pirate party (to this day, no one knows where the prizes went).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you mean, but you can check out the [Stack Exchange promotion archive](https://stackexchange.com/promos) for cool events that have happened in the past. Winter Bash is just an extension of Arqade's Hat Dash from last year, for example.

April Fool's Day is also usually good for a laugh around here.

Comment: How come other sites get so much love!?

Comment: @AustinHenley Because Stack Overflow is bigger than *all the other sites combined*.

Comment: @Aarthi Hey, it's not Stack Overflow's fault. [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) didn't know all those sweet, sweet votes would go straight to its thighs.